# How to check if a URL matches with a pattern and do something on its parameter in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, I have a list of old URL patterns. I want to check if a URL matches one of the patterns and do something on matches URLs.

For example, I have these patterns:

```
$patterns = [
    'car/{car}',
    'car/{car}/color/{color}',
]
```

And I want to check if this URL `car/nissan` matches one of the patterns, do something on the parameter like change `car/nissan` to `car/brand/nissan` (Actually it needs to run a query before changing the slug).

Also, I found this package of Spatie ([Redirect missing pages](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-missing-page-redirector/blob/afdd2100ee8c31b718efbc3a874f85ed2532c8f5/src/MissingPageRouter.php#L36)) can be helpful to write an independent method for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reading Spatie codes and I wrote these simple codes to answer here.

```
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as SimulateRequest;

class RedirectController extends Controller
{
    /** @var Router */
    protected $router;

    protected $redirectUrl;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function convertOldUrl(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $redirects = [
            '/api/car/{car}/model/{model?}' => '/api/car/{car}/model/{model}',
            '/abc' => '/efg',
        ];

        collect($redirects)->each(function ($redirects, $missingUrl) {
            $this->router->get($missingUrl, function () use ($redirects, $missingUrl) {
                $this->redirectUrl = $this->resolveRouterParameters($redirects);
            });
        });

        $simulateRequest = SimulateRequest::create($request->input('url'));
        $createdRequest = Request::createFromBase($simulateRequest);
        $this->router->dispatch($createdRequest);

        return response()->json([
            'redirect-url' => $this->redirectUrl
        ]);
    }

    protected function resolveRouterParameters(string $redirectUrl): string
    {
        foreach ($this->router->getCurrentRoute()->parameters() as $key => $value) {
            // Do something here to change $value 
            $redirectUrl = str_replace("{{$key}}", $value, $redirectUrl);
        }

        return preg_replace('/\/{[\w-]+}/', '', $redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if these are only two changes you want to check and change the URL Based on, can add redirect routes to your routes file:

`Route::redirect('/car/{car}','/car/brand/{car}');`

`Route::redirect('/car/{car}/color/{color}','/car/brand/{car}/color/{color}');`

Comment: It's doesn't seem as easy as the example, It needs to run some queries before changing the slug.

Comment: what type of queries do you want to do before? 
have you tried using middleware?

Comment: This is a RESTful API application, with redirecting old URL to new URL, but in some URLs, there is a difference in the slug. They are not the same. It's better to say some URLs are like ```car/tyta``` and new URL is ```car/toyota```.